# Poor initial load performance with heightForRowAtIndexPath and UITableView scrollToBottom

Tags: uitableview, core-data, scroll, uiscrollview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a UITableView that reads information from CoreData via the proper mechanisms (using a FetchedResultsController, etc).  This information is either textual, or a URL to a local image to load into the tableview.

Data needs to be populated in the table in a bottom-up fashion (similar to a messaging app). I am targeting iOS 8+, but if I use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath, I get terrible jerkiness on 3+ multi line labels and images.  The estimate seems way too far off unless it's a one line UILabel.  My hunch is that the cell height is being estimated in a top down manner, such that cell heights are growing from top of cell to bottom of cell.  This means that scrolling top to bottom is fine, but bottom to top is not, since the cell is being resized "downward" dynamically as I scroll upward.

I am currently using heightForRowAtIndexPath to calculate cell heights.  The problem with this is that it takes a very long time for the view to initially load because cell heights are all calculated at once.  I am using cell height caching to store cell height so that once the view has loaded, scrolling is buttery smooth.

**So my question is this**: how do you use heightForRowAtIndexPath without taking the 3-5 second initial load hit?

And follow up bonus question, is there any way to reliably use estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath when you have cells that are vastly different in height?  We're talking anywhere from 44px to 300px.  From what I've read, I can't use the estimatedHeight calculation at all in this situation.

I've exhausted all of the stackoverflow posts concerning estimatedHeight/heightForRowAtIndexPath and I'm now starting to look at the same posts more than once.  So I'm stuck.

Comment: What does instruments tell you?  Run time profiler against the app and instead of a hunch you will know for **certain** where the delay is.

Comment: The hunch was a guess as to how Apple dynamically allocates space on the screen for the cells.  I know for certain that heightForRowAtIndexPath is the cause of the initial 3-5 second load hit.  It's consuming 73% of run time when the view first loads.  Nothing else is above 1-2%.

Comment: Good to know you ran it in Instruments.  What line *inside* of heightForRowAtIndexPath is costing the time?  Is it a fetch or is it something else?  Posting the Instruments profile would be very helpful.

Comment: I get no additional information inside the time profiler for this method.  What information are you expecting me to find in here anyway?  I can't do the height calculations any more efficiently than I already am.  I think I'm going to cache the heights to disk instead to speed things up.  If you can point me to an example of this, that would be helpful.

Comment: In instruments, if you double click on the method name it will show you the source code for that method and the percentages each line is consuming.  That will tell you where the slowness is.  Start there and it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: I didn't know you could click on it and see the exact line of code.  That's insanely useful.

Turns out, I have a single NSLog statement that is causing all the slowdown in the method.  89.2%.  Moral of the story: turn off logging, especially when it's being called hundreds upon hundreds of times.

Thanks Marcus.

Answer (score 0):

why woncha stuff a few rows in the table to populate the visible area and after
the viewDidAppear start stuffing older messages on top of the table one or two
at the time with animation none, automatic or whatever.
this way with the postponement of the uitableview population
me thinks you'd get a passable performance.

or you could do it the skype way, postponing population of the table
with older messages until after table bounces off the top edge.